# Hive query from command line containing double quotes

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

How do i write following query using the hive -e "QUERY" syntax. Reason being query itself contain double quotes as well as %.

```
create external table tmp2(logdate string, time string, computername string, clientip string, uri string, qs string, localfile string, status string, referer string, w3status string, sc_bytes string, cs_bytes string, w3wpbytes string, cs_username string, cs_user_agent string, time_local string, timetakenms string, sc_substatus string, s_sitename string, s_ip string, s_port string, RequestsPerSecond string, s_proxy string, cs_version string, c_protocol string, cs_method string, cs_Host string, EndRequest_UTC string, date_local string, CPU_Utilization string, cs_Cookie string, BeginRequest_UTC string) ROW FORMAT SERDE
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
                   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
                   "input.regex" ="([0-9-]+) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+)",
                   "output.format.string"="%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s %13$s %14$s %15$s %16$s %17$s %18$s %19$s %20$s %21$s %22$s %23$s %24$s %25$s %26$s %27$s %28$s %29$s %30$s %31$s %32$s")
```

Comment: did you try escaping " with \"

Comment: @AnimeshRajJha Yes, I tried but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

This would entirely depend up how you are sending it to Hive. Just running it from the command line, you have to follow standard escaping rules for double-quotes. If you have a quote within double-quotes, you have to escape it with a backslash. Similarly, you have to escape a backslash with another backslash.

Also, be sure to escape your carriage returns within the quotes.

If we simplify your example like this:

```
create external table tmp2(logdate string, time string) ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "input.regex" = "(\".*\"|[^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*)",
    "output.format.string"="%1$s %2$s")
```

then you should be able to get it to run from the command line like this:

```
hive -e "create external table tmp2(logdate string, time string) ROW FORMAT SERDE \
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' \
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( \
    \"input.regex\" = \"(\\\".*\\\"|[^ ]*) (\\\".*\\\"|[^ ]*)\", \
    \"output.format.string\"=\"%1$s %2$s\")"
```

I would recommend simplifying your question before posting it. Sometimes the act of simplification will solve your problems for you.

Comment: Perfect answer. 
```\\\"``` does the trick. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use triple backslash

Comment: Either this answer is completely incorrect, or it lacks implementation details required for it to work. I tried many combinations of backslashes and double-double and triple-double quotes and couldn't get it to work.